# AWS Cloudformation loop over input parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I would want my CFT to take the list of subnets from the user as parameter and use that in create ALB subnets. How do I loop over subnets while creating the resource for ALB?

Something like:

```
    ApplicationLoadBalancer:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
      Properties:
        Scheme: internet-facing # or internal
        Subnets:
<% for _, subnet in subnets %>
        - Ref: <%subnet%>
<% endfor %>
        SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: ELBSecurityGroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, its **not possible** without [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or [template macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html). CloudFormation does not support loops unless you implement them yourself using the custom resource or macro.

You can also consider not using CloudFormation due to its limitations. Popular **alternative** is terraform, which has loops and could be used to achieve what you require.